# Asp.net Ajax File Upload Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Ajax File Upload Control on a user control. I have added the user control to the  web page.

According to this article https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27149

I tried the following steps

a) download the ajaxcontrolkit from the site and replaced references

I could not find the AjaxFileUpload.pre.js file to make the changes suggested on the link

b) Downloaded the [latest source](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#) but can't find the ajaxfileupload.pre.js file in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download source code of [AjaxControlToolKit](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#) from link and you can open the solution in visual studio and find the file. And you can Build the solution and get the latest DLL from this solution's bin folder as well.

Comment: i can't find the AjaxFileUpload.pre.js file in the latest https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: Of course you can't. Starting with version 15.1 toolkit structure was revamped and now this file lost _.pre_ suffix. How it is called AjaxFileUpload.js

Answer (score 0):

that link says the problem was fixed in the september 2012 release. can you update?

i think i'm using the december 2013 version and haven't had a problem iirc.

there's also another fix on your link (https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27149) at the very bottom of the page. i suppose it depends on how you use the query string.